# Conditioning on a conditioned event

Tags: probability

I am calculating the probability of error in using a particular transmission scheme and would like to know if the below is correct:
$$
P(A|B)=P(A|(C|B))P(C|B)+P(A|(C'|B))P(C'|B)
$$
What does it intuitively mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a conditioned event you can use the law of total probability (given you can partition using an event $C$) :
$P(A|B)=P(A|C\&B)P(C|B)+P(A|C^c\&B)P(C^c|B)$. Think that $A|B=Z$ and find $P(Z)$ knowing that you can partition using $C$.